# Returning all possible English dictionary words that can be formed out of a string

Tags: python, optimization, algorithm, performance

I am using an external library named `enchant` here. My problem is that I guess my program is not returning all possible English words and is slow as well for large string input.

I am using both `en_US` and `en_UK` here:

```
import enchant
import itertools
uk = enchant.Dict("en_UK")
us=enchant.Dict("en_US")
a=[] # stores all possible string combinations
ent=input('enter the word: ')
ent=ent.rstrip('\r\n')
i=3 # minimum length of words
while i<=len(ent):
  it=itertools.permutations(ent,i)
  for y in it:
    a.append("".join(y))
  i+=1 
a.sort(key=len,reverse=True)
possible_words=[]
for x in a:
  if uk.check(x) and x not in possible_words :
    possible_words.append(x) 

for x in a :
  if us.check(x) and x not in possible_words:
    possible_words.append(x)

possible_words.sort(key=len,reverse=True)
for x in possible_words:
  print(x)
```

**Example :**

```
enter the word: wsadfgh
wash
wads
wags
swag
shag
dash
fads
fags
gash
gads
haws
hags
shaw
shad
was
wad
wag
saw
sad
sag
ash
ads
fwd
fas
fad
fag
gas
gad
haw
has
had
hag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since all the permutations produced by `itertools.permutations()` are unique, there's no need to check for list membership in possible_words.

2) the permutations produced by itertools.permutations() in your (unnecessary) while loop are already ordered by length, so you don't need to sort the results, merely reverse them.

3) you can combine the US and UK dictionary lookups into one if statement.

In fact, it's possible to compress the entire lower half of your code comfortably into two lines:

```
word_perms = ("".join(j) for k in range(1, len(ent) + 1) for j in permutations(ent, k))
possible_words = reversed([i for i in word_perms if us.check(i) or uk.check(i)])
```

Answer (score 3):

As a general advice, you may want to organize your code into functions - say

- One function to receive user input and process it
- One function to generate all possible permutations for a string passed in less than a value (here 3).
- Another function to filter this based on whether the string passed in is in us or uk dictionaries
- At the end, you can combine these as a list comprehension.

Regarding your problem of performance, time the program with the itertools permutation output alone (without dict checking). My guess would be that the permutations is taking the time, but it would be nice to verify.

You may also want to check where the valid words are getting filtered. (Since you say that not all the words are being output). My guess is that permutation produces them but is not present in the enchant dictionary. But please verify.
Here is a possible rewriting of your code. It removes the redundant sorts

```
import enchant
import itertools

MIN_LEN = 3
uk = enchant.Dict("en_UK")
us = enchant.Dict("en_US")

def get_input():
  return sorted(set(input('enter the word: ').rstrip('\r\n')))

def gen_permutations(ent):
  tuples = map(lambda i: itertools.permutations(ent,i), range(MIN_LEN,len(ent)+1))
  arrr= [["".join(j) for j in i] for i in tuples]
  return list(itertools.chain(*arrr))

def filter_dict(words):
  return [x for x in words if uk.check(x) or us.check(x)]

for i in filter_dict(gen_permutations(get_input())):
  print i
```

Comment: you could probably speed this implementation up by declaring `uk` and `us` outside of `filter_dict` and by not writing to the screen (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857052/why-is-printing-to-stdout-so-slow-can-it-be-sped-up).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough karma (or whatever that's called) to comment on blufox's answer so...

- do what he says;
- but... don't use `input` use `raw_input` (you don't want to `eval` the input, right...)
- don't make it a `set` unless you don't mind losing letter repetitions
- don't build the lists, keep generators...

the (PEP8-compatible) result:

```
import itertools
import enchant

MIN_LEN = 3
uk = enchant.Dict("en_UK")
us = enchant.Dict("en_US")


def get_input():
    return raw_input('enter the word: ').rstrip('\r\n')


def gen_permutations(ent):
    perms = map(lambda i: itertools.permutations(ent, i),
                range(MIN_LEN, len(ent) + 1))
    return ("".join(tup) for perm in perms for tup in perm)


def filter_dict(words):
    return (x for x in words if uk.check(x) or us.check(x))


def test(word):
    for i in filter_dict(gen_permutations(word)):
        # print i
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # from timeit import Timer
    word = get_input()
    test(word)
    # t = Timer("test(word)", "from __main__ import test, word")
    # print t.timeit(number=500)
```

Timed with `timeit` without printing (replaced by `pass`) and without filtering (I don't want to install enchant) I get a few % lower time but mostly much less memory (the original version will use hundreds of Mb for a 10-letter word, whereas you don't need more than a few ones...).

Comment: actually i am using python 3.2 so i've to use input() instead of raw_input().
Thanks.

Comment: I agree with 2&3 :) for the first, I noticed she was running 3.2 after trying to run her example.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the 2to3 mistake ;)